# Font loading correctly design time but not runtime (WP8.1)

Tags: fonts, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

In my project, we have a bunch of icons provided in a custom icon font (a `.ttf` file). I need to show these on a Windows Phone 8.1 app.

I've included the font file in the project, and defined it as a static resource

```
<!-- this is Fonts.xaml -->
<ResourceDictionary>
    <!-- ... -->
    <FontFamily x:Key="Icons">
        /Resources/Fonts/custom_icons.ttf#custom_icons
    </FontFamily>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

as well as merged it into the app's resource dictionary

```
<!-- in App.xaml -->
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergeDictionaries>
            <!-- ... -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
<Application.Resources>
```

And when I want to include an icon, I do something like

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource Icons}" FontSize="30">
    &#xF0D5;
</TextBlock>
```

In design time (e.g. Blend or VS visual editor), this icon shows up OK, but when I run the app in the emulator, I get the rectangle that indicates a missing character.

I think there's a problem with my font file - icons from Font Awesome included exactly the same way work as expected - but I have no idea how to troubleshoot further.

What could cause this? If I need to change something about the font (i.e. ask the designers to change something), what is it that should change?

Comment: Not sure it is the same problem, but I had that once myself - and found a solution too. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085818/custom-font-usage-in-windows-phone-8

Comment: @Depechie: Thanks for the reply - as you'll notice in my first code sample, I've already done what was suggested there...

Comment: Euh I don't see that, the problem I had was that the declaration of the fontfamily needed to have a full path, your example doesn't contain the Value="/PhoneApp1;component... part indicating a full path ( so appname is missing ). Look at the answer that was accepted.